# $S^{n-1} \to D^n$ is a Cofibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $D^n$ the $n$ dimensional disc and $S^{n-1}$ it's boundary. We have then a canocical embeding $i:S^{n-1} \hookrightarrow D^n$. How to proof that $i$ is a cofibration?

My attempts: 
Obviously $D^n \cong CS^{n-1}$ where $CS^{n-1}$ is the cone defined via $$CS^{n-1}:= (S^{n-1} \times [0;1]) / (S^{n-1} \times 0)$$

So it stays to prove that the map $S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}\times \{1\} \subset CS^{n-1}$ is a cofibration.

But I don't know how to prove this

Comment: Do you know HEP?

Comment: Yes, I tried also without success to find a compatble $CS^{n-1} \to Y^I$. Seems not to work explicite...

Comment: I wrote out formulas showing that $X \to CX$ is a cofibration for any $X$, but the question was put on hold, and I don't know why. This can be a hint, though, the problem is equally easy with a general space $X$.  In fact, a nice starting point is to think about $X  = \{*\}$.

Comment: Well, in this case $CX = I$ such that I encounter again the same problem to find a $I \to \to Y^I$ with is compatible with inclusion $\{*\} \to I$ and $f: I \to Y$

Comment: I suppose that if I could conclude that $\{*\} \to I$ is a cofibration then also that $\{*\} \times X  \to I \times X$ is also a cofibration. Since cofibrations are stable under pushouts then I get that $\{*\} \to CX$ is a cofibation too, since that's a quotient. But that don't help me with an arbitrary $X$

Comment: Yes, it doesn't follow formally like that, but the formula you obtain for $\{*\} \to I$ can be applied to the general case. It could be useful to know the equivalent formulation that $A\to Y$ is a cofibration if and only if $A\times I \cup Y\times \{0\}$ is a retract of $Y\times I$. The formula for the retraction is the place to start I had in mind.

Comment: For completeness, here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729826/show-explicitly-x-to-cx-is-cofibration ) is a solution showing that $X\to CX$ is a cofibration for general $X$, in particular, this applies to $S^{n-1} \to D^{n}$.