# Show explicitly $X \to CX$ is Cofibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be topological space and 
$$CX:=(X\times [0;1]) / (X \times \{0\})$$

it's cone. $X$ can via identification $X \cong X \times \{1\}$ be enbedded into $CX$.

I wan't to show ***explicitely*** that $i:X \to CX$ is a cofibration by writing concretely the morphism $$m: CX \to Y^I$$

commutating with the morphisms in following diagram:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X  @>{H}  >> Y^I   \\
@VViV  @VVev_0V   \\
CX @>{f}>> Y 
\end{CD}
$$

Indeed I know that there are a lot of ways to show implicitely that $i$ is a cofibration.

But here I'm interested in the concrete shape of the map $m$.

Comment: My last post about this was deleted. Once it seems like this question will not be deleted, I will post my answer again if no one else has.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm quite curious how they explicitly look like since in literature this statement is proved only with abstract arguments (like as you mentiented wich push out property of mapping cylinder or similar...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set conventions: I will define $CX = X\times I /X\times \{0\}$, I will identify $X \cong X\times \{1\} \subset CX$. We define a retraction $r: CX \times I \to (X\times I) \cup (CX \times \{0\})$ as follows:

$$r(((x,s),t))=
\begin{cases}
((x,1), t-2 +2s) & \text{if}\ \ \  1-\frac{1}{2}t\le s \le 1\\
((x, \frac{2s}{2-t}),0)& \text{if}\ \ \  0 \le s \le 1-\frac{1}{2}t
\end{cases}$$

It is necessary to check that the function is well defined, though in that case it is clearly continuous. One also needs to check that it is a retraction.

Doing the case of $X = \{*\}$ by drawing a picture of a square and visualizing the retraction onto the left and top edge gives the idea for the formulas.

There is a more sophisticated approach to this type of thing using NDR pairs, and it is fairly easy to prove that $(CX, X)$ is an NDR pair. One advantage is it works out such formulas behind the scenes.

Finally, once you have obtained $r$, how do you obtain $m: CX\to Y^I$? First, note that $H: X\to Y^I$ defines by duality a map $H':X\times I \to Y$ given by $H'(x,t) = H(x)(t)$. The map $f: CX\to Y$ can be viewed as a map $f': CX\times \{0\} \to Y$ in the obvious way, by identification. Thus, we obtain a map $H'\cup f' : (X\times I) \cup (CX \times \{0\}) \to Y$, which agrees on the overlap by the commutativity of your diagram above. Therefore, $H'\cup f'$ is continuous. Now, define $m': CX\times I \to Y$ by $m' = (H'\cup f') \circ r$. The dual map $m: CX \to Y^I$ is the map $m$ you seek. For clarity, the map $m$ is defined by $m((x,s))(t) = m'((x,s),t)$. Hopefully, this clarifies the connection between the retraction and the lifting problem above.

Comment: This question was answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681002/the-inclusion-x-to-cx-is-a-cofibration I am essentially reposting that answer because it was deleted as "off-topic" which I find baffling.